# I want to create a custom keyboard layout for ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, 20.04

Is there an easy way to create a custom keyboard layout in ubuntu. I have seen the many posts about the custom keyboard layouts, but they seemed long for what I need. All need is an American keyboard layout with a <kbd>£</kbd> built-in. Yes I know the international us layout has it in but that keyboard layout makes typing <kbd>"</kbd> very hard. If there is some sort of tool which will allow me to do this easily then that would be great.

Comment: "English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)"?

Comment: thanks that worked. I just wasn't looking hard enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Gunnar Hjalmarsson for the answer.
Found there is a keyboard layout with what I wanted already on it. Although it has so many unnecessary keys on it I just wanted a simple US layout with the <kbd>£</kbd> and working <kbd>"</kbd>, with this keyboard layout there are so many unused keys which I would never use. It's not the end of the world. I can bare with it. It's fine.

Comment: I kind of thought that creating a custom layout for only that symbol would be to overdo it. Good to hear that my suggestion proved to fit your needs.